# Angular router outlet & wildcard issue

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular13

Example of a working code

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WorkstationTemplateComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'workstation',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/root-content/root-content.module').then(m => m.RootContentModule)
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        component: RouterNotFoundComponent,
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

Now if I try to add outlet to wildcard, same as previous array index, it does not work, the components all load expect the wild card.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WorkstationTemplateComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'workstation',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/root-content/root-content.module').then(m => m.RootContentModule)
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        outlet: 'workstation', // <-- if I add this, error throws a routing not found if I simulate a wrong path
        component: RouterNotFoundComponent,
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

I might be missing a logic here.

In the first example it somewhat works if I use two router outlets, on which one of them is not named but it is not my goal

The goal is to end up using

```html
     <router-outlet name="workstation"></router-outlet>
```

instead of

```html
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="workstation"></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the wild-card route which handles all other routes not defined in your routing as shown below. Add it as the last property of the `Routes`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {...},
  {...},
  // Handle all other routes
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
```